# custom http route for an API POST without URI parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, httprequest, uri

I have a post http without header URI parameters, in the image you can see API
[image]

When i call it I get the error

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

I'm trying to add a custom route as this in the config file

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ApiByAction",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: null,
           constraints: new { action = "accettaTickets" }
            );
```

because the default needs a URI parameter

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but I get the same error.
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have controller with proper action method for this URL. Try to add such controller with default route configuration.

```
public class WATicketController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> accettaTickets()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```